# Detecting on the browser when user switches Phantom wallet accounts

Tags: reactjs, solana

So I have a react app with nextjs where I'd need to get an event trigger when the user uses the Phantom wallet extension and switches accounts. I cannot find anything relevant on their docs: https://docs.phantom.app/

I was wondering if anyone encounter this issue. Basically I have the window.solana object but it does not have a trigger for when the user siwtches accounts

Answer (score 5):

So Phantom itself does not expose any account switching specific API on their `window.solana` object.

There are some tricks you can do to find out when the account switches though.

You can continuously poll for the currently connected account and set the publicKey to some variable. When the publicKey changes, you can trigger your event.

Example psuedocode:

```
let currentKey = '';

poll(() => {
  if (/* wallet available and connected */) {
    await /* Action that updates publicKey */
    if (currentKey !== wallet.publicKey.toBase58()) {
      currentKey = wallet.publicKey.toBase58();
      this.publicKey = wallet.publicKey;
      this.emit('change')
    }
  }
})
```

You can find a writeup and PR we currently have on wallet-adapter going over this flow [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/pull/109)

Comment: I do have a question tho, what method do you use to update the publicKey or the window.solana object? So you get the new account

Comment: Because that's the issue here, there is no function to update it

Comment: @SergiuTonț When you do the eager connection with Phantom, it will update the publicKey inside the window.solana object to match what is shown in the wallet. So in Phantom's case this would be https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/establishing-a-connection#eagerly-connecting

Comment: what is `poll` on reactJs?

Answer (score 0):

Phantom now emits `accountChanged` event: https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/establishing-a-connection#changing-accounts